# Do I need to sanitize data from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I know you should always use prepared statements (or sanitize) for data inputted by the user. We are doing that. My question is, once data has been input using prepared statements and is sitting in my database, do I need to use prepared statements again if I grab data from the database, manipulate it myself (i.e. no user involvement) and then put it back in the database?

I know if I sanitize data on the way in from the user, I need to sanitize it when manipulating it myself and putting it back into the database, too. But does this apply to prepared statements as well?

So, to summarize, data from user -> use prepared statement -> into database. But do I need to do the following when working that the user-submitted-but-prepared-data-before-storage: data from database -> use prepared statement -> into database?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't hurt, though I don't think it's necessary, in a strict sense of the word.

Comment: If the data could be entered by users, then sanitizing is a good idea.  If the data is programmatic, then it should not be necessary.

Comment: I would.  Who's to say someone didn't run a script to update data in a way that would cause issues later.  Or later on, someone doesn't sanitize data and it gets in though an import or merge.  Better to be safe than sorry!  Though, I'm not a big fan of altering data without user approvals...

Comment: @Everyone: Thanks for the responses. Let's assume no one is able to change the data after the data is in my database except for me. Do I still need to use prepared statement when manipulating it?

Comment: if there is no user intervention and you have complete control over it, and that a user cannot manipulate anything, then no; you don't need to.

Comment: Odd question. Don't you call the same code to store your data when it comes from user or when it comes from your code? If not then you seem to need to do some refactoring. If you have one method for this then it already does all the sanitization as user data comes that way. So what is really the question? :)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski If I was using the same code for both, why would I be asking this question o_O

Comment: I don't think Gordon or Fred understood your question the same way I did. Do you need to "sanitize" the data? No, not in the way we normally think of what "sanitize" means.  But the question that was asked... do you need to *follow the same*  prepare -> bind -> execute  *pattern* because the value you fetch is potentially unsafe?  YES.  That pattern makes it "safe" to insert unsanitary values, it doesn't store "sanitzed" versions of the values in the database.

Comment: You must treat data that *ever* came from a user as potentially dangerous. It could be malicious or it could be a name like `O'Brien`, but that doesn't matter. Either way, if it came from a user, you need to use prepared statements *every time* you need to pass it to the database.

Comment: @user4951834 if so then your question makes no much sense for me. Because you are now doing this already. Always. Adding special condition to not do that just because it is processed internally would be both silly and also dangerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it came from a user *at any point*, yes, you need to use prepared statements when you insert it again.

Imagine you take malicious data and save it using a prepared statement. You then pull it out, do something to it, and save it back to the database. Unless you just happened to make it safe, it's still dangerous. It's never safe to assume that user-submitted data is non-malicious. If it wasn't safe to assume that the data was non-malicious when you first received it, it doesn't magically become safe when it sits in the database for a while.

Comment: +10 better and more concisely presented than my answer.  essentially the same ideas I tried to convey. (I think Gordon and Fred missed that OP was using the term "sanitize" as a reference to the prepare->bind->execute pattern.)

Comment: Thanks, @spencer7593. I actually thought your answer was very good, as well (you got a vote from me). Just wanted to put a slightly different spin on it.

Comment: Ed, I think this answer (your answer) has a better "spin" than mine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to follow the same pattern.

Consider you have a varchar column which you've inserted values into. For sake of example, let's call it `last_name`.

Someone may have inserted a value of `'O'Reilly'` into that column.

If that was done following the pattern

prepare -> bind -> execute

The value stored in the column in the database is going to be `O'Reilly`, containing that single quote.

If you later fetch that value from the database, just because you got it from the database, that doesn't mean it is now "safe" for inclusion in the text of a SQL statement.

If you want to use that value in another SQL statement, you're faced with the *same* problem you had when a user first entered the value.

So you either need to follow the same pattern `prepare -> bind -> execute` (, or the string value will need to be properly escaped if it's included in the text of a SQL statement.)

---

If you are just referencing the name of the column that contains the unsafe value, then you can safely use that in a SQL statement, e.g.

```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _tmp_last_names
  AS 
  SELECT t.last_name FROM mytable t
  ;
```

---

The pattern of using prepared statements with bind placeholders doesn't "sanitize" the data. It's just a mechanism that avoids some potential problems with some data values.

An "unsanitary" value supplied for a bind placeholder will get stored in the database. It will be the same "unsanitary" value, not some "sanitized" version of the value.

But if you've done some other logic (apart from the prepare -> bind -> execute pattern) to "sanitize" all values stored in the database, then it wouldn't be strictly necessary to re-execute that same logic. Assuming that no other process has subsequently replace a sanitary value in the database with an unsanitary value.

Answer (score 4):

Why wouldn't you sanitize it? Any point where you are not sanitizing the data is an unnecessary opening no matter how improbable abuse of that opening seems.

If you are doing a one-off script then don't worry about sanitizing. Run it and then remove it. If it is part of your program then sanitize it because you easily can. Why are you considering using a different save method from the one you are using to sanitize the user submitted data?
Include save in the same method for both actions regardless of how it was initiated so everything will look and behave similarly and always sanitize eg

```
DB()->updateColumn('table', $data)->where('id', $uid);
```

This is just a guess but it seems like the approach you are taking does not consider where code reuse might be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add in that with all this talk of sanitizing (and my own searching) there's no explanation on how to actually sanitize the MySQL data before it gets put back into PHP? (Psst: I don't have the 50 rep needed to be able to comment anyone's answer but I really fealt the need to say this since it's what I'm searching for at this very moment.)